# DRF serializer get liked data with post by request user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm making a social app like facebook.
when getting post(at news feed) data I would like to get Boolean if I pressed like about that post.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    uploader = models.ForeignKey(User)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    point = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    isPointReceived = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    content = models.TextField()
    uploadedTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    # editedTime = models.DateTimeField()
    def __str__(self):
        return ("[uploader = " + self.uploader.username + "]") + (", [id = " + (str)(self.id) + "]") + ("[content = " + self.content[:50] + "]")


class PostLike(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='postLikes')
    liker = models.ForeignKey(User)
    def __str__(self):
        return "Like" + "| [Post = " + (str)(self.post) + "]" + ", [Liker = " + self.liker.username + "]"
```

serializers.py

```
class PostLikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PostLike
        fields = '__all__'


class PostListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    uploader = UserDetailSerializer()
    isMine = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    isLiked = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    postComments = PostCommentSerializer(many=True, allow_null=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('uploader', 'id',  'likes', 'point', 'isPointReceived', 'content', 'uploadedTime', 'postComments', 'isMine', 'isLiked',)


    def get_isMine(self, obj):
        requestUser = CurrentUserDefault()
        return obj.objects.fileter(uploader=requestUser).exists()
        # return obj.filter(uploader=requestUser)


    def get_isLiked(self, obj):
        requestUser = CurrentUserDefault()
        return PostLike.objects.filter(post=obj, liker=requestUser).exists()
        #
        # try:
        #     PostLike.objects.get(post=obj, liker=requestUser)
        #     return True
        # except:
        #     return False
```

I tried lot of dirty stuffs. but there was no solution..

conclusion:
HTF to get data about, if user has a record of `PostLike(post=post, user=user)`

- how to get user in serializer Class.

or should I approach this in different ways?
like managing liked data in APIView or whatever etc...

help!

========EDITED==========
final code should look like this.
in serialziers.py

```
class PostListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    uploader = UserDetailSerializer()
    postComments = PostCommentSerializer(many=True, allow_null=True)
    postLikes = PostLikeSerializer(many=True, allow_null=True)
    postImages = PostImageSerializer(many=True, allow_null=True)
    isMine = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    isLiked = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('uploader', 'id',  'likes', 'content', 'uploadedTime', 'postComments', 'postLikes', 'postImages', 'isMine', 'isLiked',)


    def get_isMine(self, obj):
        requestUser = self.context['request'].user
        return obj.uploader == requestUser


    def get_isLiked(self, obj):
        requestUser = self.context['request'].user
        return PostLike.objects.filter(post=obj, liker=requestUser).exists()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a user from serializer context inside serializer method:

```
self.context['request'].user
```

It passed from a method `get_serializer_context` which originally created in a `GenericAPIView`:

```
class GenericAPIView(APIView):
    ....
    def get_serializer_context(self):
        """
        Extra context provided to the serializer class.
        """
        return {
            'request': self.request,
            'format': self.format_kwarg,
            'view': self
        }
```

As you can see you could also get `format` and `view` from context. You could also override this method for set additional context.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_isLiked(self, obj):
    requestUser = self.context['request'].user
    return PostLike.objects.filter(post=obj, liker=requestUser).exists()
```

If results have 12 objects it will execute 12 similar query, which increase increase your response time. I am looking for solution so that I can make it with one query. Don't know how can I do that.

Comment: yes. this increases request-response time.. even i was looking for a way to overcome that. did u get any leads?

Answer (score 0):

def get_isLiked(self, obj):
requestUser = self.context['request'].user
return PostLike.objects.filter(post=obj, liker=requestUser).exists()

You should to get all PostLike fields in cache and use prefetch_related method in your query set. This thing will check all entries using cache, not multiple queries.

For example:

```
def get_isLiked(self, obj):
    requestUser = self.context['request'].user
    likes = PostLike.objects.all()
    return likes.filter(post=obj, liker=requestUser).exists()
```

and somewhere in models or views or managers in "get_queryset" you should add:

```
queryset.prefetch_related('postlike')
```